# how to use a specific python API in Django?

Tags: python, django

Can anyone tell me how can I use [Pybel](http://openbabel.org/pybel.html) in django for creating a web abased application.Pybel is a python module that helps in using Open Babel a software for conversion of chemical compounds.

I want to create an web app which can use different functionalites of [Pybel](http://openbabel.org/docs/2.3.1/UseTheLibrary/Python_PybelAPI.html). since Django is python based, so I thought this can work.
Since I am new to django if anyone can point me to tutorial or something that can help me doing will also be greatly helpful.

waiting for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You simple import the module and use it. Django is python so you can do whatever you do in a non-web-based python app, too.